# ColdFusion FW/1 migration from 2.5 to 3.5

Tags: coldfusion, fw1

I guess at some point we had Fw/1 2.2 and upgraded to 2.5.  So developer set variables.framework.enableGlobalRC = true to work in 2.5 as 2.2.

So now my issue is we want to upgrade to FW/1 3.5 and not really sure how to remove this from out application.  We did the wiring of DI/1 and that seems to work, but now we have the RC variables that are set in the setupRequest that are not available to the controller to reference.

Might be simple or complicated not sure at this point how to move forward.  Any suggestions would help.

Thank you.